# What does Yellow Alert mean?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

When the Enterprise goes to yellow alert, what exactly does that mean? In the episode *The Neutral Zone* the ship goes to yellow alert - and then later the shields are raised. I was under the impression that yellow alert meant shields should be automatically raised?

**What does yellow alert mean when it is called**?

Comment: It's somewhere between condition green and red alert. I can activate it for you, but it [will mean changing the lightbulb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qa_gZ_7sdZg).

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Yellow_alert

Comment: @Valorum hmm looking at this it looks like there is a scripting error in that episode

Comment: The implication seems to be that shields are energised, but not necessarily raised. That fits nicely with what's seen in the episode.

Comment: Copy paste, copy paste. Done

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [TNG: Technical Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual), when a "Yellow Alert" is called, a considerable number of things happen.

> During Yellow Alert condition, all active bridge stations are
>   automatically brought to Full Enable Mode. Auto diagnostics (Level 4)
>   are initiated for all primary and tactical systems Ops is responsible
>   for evaluating all current operations and shipboard activities and
>   suspending any that may interfere with ship's readiness to respond to
>   potential crisis situations

and

> Yellow and Red Alert protocols call for cross-trained personnel with
>   noncritical primary assignments to be available for their secondary
>   assignments as necessary.

and

> Yellow and Red Alert operating rules generally require the presence of
>   at least two command personnel, in addition to Conn and Ops.

and

> All on-duty crew and attached personnel are informed of the potential crisis via panel display and are directed to prepare for
>   possible emergency action. Second shift crew personnel are also
>   alerted and those in key operational positions are directed to prepare
>   for possible duty on five minutes' notice. Cross-trained second shift
>   personnel are directed to prepare for possible duty in their secondary
>   assignments. Specific systems preparations include:
>
> - Level 4 automated diagnostic series run on all ship's primary and tactical systems to determine ship's current readiness status.
> - If presently off-line, warp power core brought to full operating condition and maintained at 20% power output. Level 4 diagnostics
>     provide a status report on warp capability including maximum available
>     engine output.
> - Main impulse propulsion system brought to full operating condition. At least one backup reactor element is brought to hot
>     standby. In Yellow Alert status triggered by potential hostile action,
>     Saucer Module impulse propulsion system is brought to partial standby.
> - All tactical and long-range sensor arrays are brought to full operational status. Secondary mission use of any sensor elements can
>     be overridden if required by bridge.
> - **Deflector systems brought to full standby. Secondary deflector generators brought to partial standby. All operational backup
>     generators are energized to partial readiness.**
> - Phaser banks are energized to partial standby. Power conduits are enabled, and targeting scanners are activated. Level 4 automated
>     diagnostics verify operational status.
> - Photon torpedo launchers are brought to partial stand-by. One torpedo device is energized to partial launch readiness and primed
>     with a standard antimatter charge, unless specifically overridden by
>     Ops or Tactical. Level 4 automated diagnostics confirm operational
>     status.
> - The Battle Bridge is brought to partial standby status and backup bridge crews are notified for possible duty in the event of possible
>     Saucer sep maneuvers.
> - Two of the three shuttlebays are brought to launch readiness. The number of shuttlecraft at launch readiness is maintained at one.
> - Onboard sensors record the location of all personnel and alert Security of any anomalous activity. Location and activity information
>     is recorded for postmission analysis.
> - Level 5 automated diagnostics are performed to verify readiness of autonomous survival and recovery vehicle systems (lifeboats).

Note that although secondary deflector systems (e.g. the "shields") are brought to *readiness*, **calling a Yellow Alert doesn't automatically engage the shields at full power,** an action that might seem, to an enemy, to be a provocative action.

Comment: On a related note, always wondered why Riker kept asking for the shields to be raised & weapons readied on a Red Alert.  You'd think that was automatic.

Comment: @Tim - So that the audience know that the shields are raised and the weapons are readied.

Comment: Because a Red Alert does not necessarily mean shields are activated. They are in standby mode to conserve power until the last possible second.